# The expected value of a function of a random variable

Tags: probability

The expected value of a function of a random variable can be calculated by $$E(U(X)) = \int_{-\infty} ^\infty {u(x)f_X(x)}\mathrm{d}x$$

Show that this formula is true, by using the pdf of the random variable Y=u(X).

I tried using the inverse transformation method but I could not get to this formula. Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: The inverse transformation method is the way to go. What do you think the pdf of $u(X)$ is?

Comment: Following the inverse transformation method, I came to this: $$\frac{dU^{-1}(y)}{dy}f_X(U^{-1}(y))$$. However, I don't see how this would give me the desired answer.

Comment: Okay, that should be $u^{-1}$, not $U^{-1}$. And what happens if, in your integral for $E(U(X))$, you perform the U-substituion $x\to u^{-1}(y)$?

Comment: I am not so sure how the substitution you proposed works. Could you please show me how it is done?

Comment: Do you know, in general, how to do [integration by substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution)?

Comment: Yes I do know that. I am not sure about this particular case though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the integral
$$
\mathbb{E}(U(X))=\int_{-\infty}^\infty{u(x)f_X(x)\mathbb{d}x}
$$
perform the substitution
$$
x\mapsto u^{-1}(y),\quad \mathbb{d}x\mapsto\left(\frac{\mathbb{d}}{\mathbb{d}y}u^{-1}(y)\right)\mathbb{d}y.
$$
This leads to
$$
\mathbb{E}(U(X)) = \int_{u(-\infty)}^{u(\infty)}{yf_X(u^{-1}(y))\left(\frac{\mathbb{d}}{\mathbb{d}y}u^{-1}(y)\right)}\mathbb{d}y,
$$
which you recognise as
$$
\int_{}^{}{y f_{u(X)}(y)\mathbb{d}y}.
$$

Note that you want $u$ to enjoy some monotonicity properties for this technique to work.