# Expected value of the result of a function when its input parameter is passed from an exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

Say we obtain a random number from an exponential distribution with $\lambda = \frac{1}{4}$. The numbers are passed into $f(x) = (2x + 1)(2x - 1)$. How do i find the expected value of the result?

My first assumption was to do 
$$
E(X) = E(g(\frac{1}{4}e^{-\frac{1}{4}x})) = \dfrac{1}{4}[-2e^{-\frac{1}{4}x}]_{-\infty}^{\infty} - [x]_{-\infty}^{\infty}
$$ 
However that would be incorrect as we would get an infinity.

I came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352854/the-expected-value-of-a-function-of-a-random-variable), which would imply the right way to solve this problem is 
$$
E(g(f(x))) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{4}e^{-\frac{1}{4}x})(2x + 1)(2x - 1)
$$
Though I am unsure if that is correct, or why it would be right. Could someone help explain to me if this is the right way to solve it and the intuition behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct expression is $\int_0^{\infty} \frac 1 4 e^{-\frac 1 4 x} (2x+1)(2x-1) \, dx$. This can be evaluated by repeatedly  integrating by parts.

Comment: my bad, i forgot the -ve sign. Could you explain why it should be that way though?

Comment: You also wrote $-\infty$ to $\infty$ instead of $0$ to $\infty$. If $X$ is a random variable with density $f$ and $g$ is any measurable function the $Eg(X)=\int f(x)g(x)\, dx$. In this case $f(x)=\frac 1 4 e^{-\frac 1 4 x}$ for $x>0$ and $g(x)=(2x-1)(2x+1)$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you link me to a theorem that states that? Your help is very much appreciated

Comment: This is the formula for an integral with respect to a measure induced by a measurable function. It is available in measure theoretic treatments of probability theory. It must also be available in other books (which don't use measure theory) but I don't have any such book with me.